# How to calculate percentage across two tables in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables as shown in the screenshot below:

***Table1***

[image]

*Table1 is the total number of New student and Refresher who attended the lecture for respective month.*

***Table2***

[image]

*Table2 is the data for those students who submitted their homework.*

My goal is to calculate how many % of New student and Refresher submitted their homework among the student who attended the lecture. I tried to did some calculation but it doesn't work in the way that I want. Below is how I calculated the % :

**New Measure in Table1:**

```
Total new student attended = SUM(Table1[New])
```

**New Measure in Table2:**

```
Total student did homework = COUNT(Table2[Type of Student])
```

**New Measure in Table2:**

```
Number of new student did homework = CALCULATE([Total student did homework],Table2[Type of Student] = "I am a new student.")
```

**New Measure in Table2:**

```
% New student did homework = [Number of new student did homework] / Table1[Total new student attended]
```

The result is not right. I think there is something wrong in the New Measure for Table1, but I'm not sure how to correct it, hope to get some help and advice. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new table from **Table2** with this below **Power Query Advance Editor** code-

```
let
    Source = Table2,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Month Name"}, {
        {"Count_new", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each ([Type of Student] = "I am a new student."))), Int64.Type}, 
        {"Count_refresher", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each ([Type of Student] = "I am refresher student."))), Int64.Type}
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Now you will have a new table with data like- month wise new and refresher count. You can now join the new table with **Table1** using **month** column and calculate your required count and percentages.